# Is it possible to use DNSCrypt and simple-adblock together on a LEDE router?

Tags: networking, adblock

I'm running a router loaded with LEDE. DNSCrypt works so far, but I want to add Simple Adblock to replace my browser-based ad-blocking. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

DNSCrypt encrypts requests between client and server. I think the better place to block ads is dnsmasq.
This is my setup:
Make sure you have dnsmasq and wget.
Create bash script `/root/update_ads.sh`:

```
wget -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts | awk '$1 == "0.0.0.0" { print "address=/"$2"/0.0.0.0/"}' > /etc/dnsmasq.d/ad_hosts.conf

/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

It pulls the latest list of ad hosts, converts to dnsmasq format(NXDOMAIN response) and restarts dnsmasq

To do it periodically add this line to cron:

```
0 0 * * * /root/update_ads.sh
```

Check if dnsmasq includes conf files from `/etc/dnsmasq.d/`. `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` should have this line `conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d/,*.conf`